# Problem with aligning results in table (longtable & siunitx)

Tags: longtable, siunitx

I am creating a table with regression results. This is the result:

[image]

Aligning at the decimal point works fine. Two problems remain:

- When having negative value, a space is inserted between the number and the stars.
- The headers only show when using multicolumn. Now, they are not really aligned with anything. Using 'c' or 'r' in the multicolumn environment does not really solve the problem.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{3cm}SS@{}} 
\centering
\kill

\toprule
 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Target}    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$R^2$}     \\*

\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot

% body 
OIS\_1Y            & 1.67* & 0.55     \\
OIS\_2Y            & 1.61*** & 0.42   \\
OIS\_5Y            & -1.15*** & 0.25  \\
OIS\_10Y           & -0.09** & 0.09   \\
stoxx50euro        & -0.04*  & 0.06   \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can help siunitx a bit by specifying a suitable `table-format` for your columns, see section "4.12 Tabular material" of the siunitx documentation for more details.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{3cm}S[table-format=-1.2,table-align-text-after=true,table-space-text-post={***}]S[table-format=1.2]@{}} 
\centering
\kill

\toprule
 & {Target}    & {$R^2$}     \\*

\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot

% body 
OIS\_1Y            & 1.67* & 0.55     \\
OIS\_2Y            & 1.61*** & 0.42   \\
OIS\_5Y            & -1.15*** & 0.25  \\
OIS\_10Y           & -0.09** & 0.09   \\
stoxx50euro        & -0.04*  & 0.06   \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! For the titles, just insterting {} around the header solves this problem